# How is it possible to deploy an archive with puppet

Tags: ansible, puppet, idempotent

I have been using ansible to deploy artifacts created in jenkins. The play looks like this:

1. Transfer the tar.gz archive to the remote host (archive contains python code)
2. stop the python code (it has been setup as a systemd service which symlinks to the script inside /home/arl/code
3. Delete the /home/arl/code folder (recursively)
4. Extract the tar.gz file into /home/arl
5. Start the systemd script for the code.

In puppet, you can manage services using the service provider. But since you want to manage a 'state' you can't declare the resource python_service as 'stopped', and then later in the manifest as 'started' as this will lead to a duplicate declaration error. In ansible, which is imperative this is easily achievable.

Is there a way to achieve it in puppet?

Comment: You want this: https://forge.puppet.com/puppetlabs/transition

Answer (score 1):

For what you are doing you would want to use a series of `Exec` resource types and use `->` resource ordering operator. So you puppet manifest would look something like this:

```
scp_tarball_command = '/usr/bin/scp ...';
stop_python = '/usr/sbin/systemd stop whatever';
delete_code_dir = '/bin/rm -rf /home/arl/code';
untar_tarball = '/usr/bin/tar -xzf ...';
start_python = '/usr/sbin/systemd start whatever';

exec { $scp_tarball_command: creates => 'whatever'} ->
exec { $stop_python: refreshonly => true} ->
exec { $delete_code_dir: refreshonly => true} ->
exec { $untar_tarball: refreshonly => true} ->
exec { $start_python: refreshonly => true}
```

You'll want to take a look here for details on resource ordering : https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.3/types/exec.html

Also I would suggest placing that code in class and replacing the hardcoded stuff with class parameters.

Comment: Hey, I'm familiar with relationships and ordering, and I'm also familiar with exec. It just seems to me very 'un-puppetly' to work like that. Can you tell me if thats considered a best practice or simply a viable solution?

Comment: It is sort of unpuppetity, but if you had your code packaged in an RPM you could better follow the puppet pattern of `package >> file >> service`.

Comment: If you packaged you python code into a python package you might be possible to use `pip` as a `provider` in a `package` resource declaration.

Comment: The pip idea is a good one for python. My main challenge is dealing with a situation where a a file in the code dir might be locked by a running process. Again, from an imperative approach this is fairly easy to deal with. *Stop -> *Overwrite Code -> *Start. For example, if you manage nginx with puppet, and want to upgrade it, puppet needs to probably stop the service before it updates the code dir and then start it again. I'll take a look at how some of the other modules are achieving this. Thanks for your advice.